# Chart.js combined line and bar chart with differing data points

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to use chart.js to plot the daily generation of my solar panels combined with the month total in one chart, much like in the image below. Both graphs alone are easy to produce, but all examples I find for a combined chart have the same amount of datapoints for both charts. I have 12 for the bar chart and 365 or 366 for the line chart.
Is it possible to make this?

[image: Solar production]

Comment: As you are a new contributor, please remember to mark an answer as **accepted answer** if you feel it solved your issue. That way, other contributors would see that your issue has been solved and can concentrate on other questions pending - thank you

Answer (score 4):

### Using `timeseries` as x-Axis, applying additional trick:

Try following:

1. **set x-axis type** to [timeseries](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/next/axes/cartesian/timeseries.html):
   for each x-Axis `scales: {'daily-x-axis': { type: 'timeseries' ...`
   for x-Axis type 'time' or 'timeseries' to work, you need additional libraries  (like moment.js and its adapter)
2. **Trick**: for monthly totals in your data, use **first day of month as x value**, like `x: "2021-01-01"` etc ...
3. **style your bars and labels/ticks**, adding `backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.5)'`, x- and y-Axis label colors, color of ticks, etc ...

```js
let dailyGeneration = [{x: '2021-01-01', y: 1},{x: '2021-01-02', y: 3},{x: '2021-01-03', y: 2},{x: '2021-01-04', y: 5},{x: '2021-01-05', y: 8},{x: '2021-01-06', y: 2},{x: '2021-01-07', y: 11},{x: '2021-01-08', y: 10},{x: '2021-01-09', y: 7},{x: '2021-01-10', y: 6},{x: '2021-01-11', y: 1.5},{x: '2021-01-12', y: 3},{x: '2021-01-13', y: 4},{x: '2021-01-14', y: 6},{x: '2021-01-15', y: 0.5},{x: '2021-01-16', y: 3},{x: '2021-01-17', y: 9},{x: '2021-01-18', y: 8},{x: '2021-01-19', y: 7},{x: '2021-01-20', y: 6},{x: '2021-01-21', y: 6},{x: '2021-01-22', y: 4},{x: '2021-01-23', y: 3},{x: '2021-01-24', y: 1},{x: '2021-01-25', y: 1},{x: '2021-01-26', y: 2},{x: '2021-01-27', y: 5},{x: '2021-01-28', y: 8},{x: '2021-01-29', y: 7},{x: '2021-01-30', y: 12},{x: '2021-01-31', y: 2},
{x: '2021-02-01', y: 1},{x: '2021-02-02', y: 3},{x: '2021-02-03', y: 2},{x: '2021-02-04', y: 5},{x: '2021-02-05', y: 8},{x: '2021-02-06', y: 2},{x: '2021-02-07', y: 11},{x: '2021-02-08', y: 10},{x: '2021-02-09', y: 7},{x: '2021-02-10', y: 6},{x: '2021-02-11', y: 1.5},{x: '2021-02-12', y: 3},{x: '2021-02-13', y: 4},{x: '2021-02-14', y: 6},{x: '2021-02-15', y: 0.5},{x: '2021-02-16', y: 3},{x: '2021-02-17', y: 9},{x: '2021-02-18', y: 8},{x: '2021-02-19', y: 7},{x: '2021-02-20', y: 6},{x: '2021-02-21', y: 6},{x: '2021-02-22', y: 4},{x: '2021-02-23', y: 3},{x: '2021-02-24', y: 1},{x: '2021-02-25', y: 1},{x: '2021-02-26', y: 2},{x: '2021-02-27', y: 5},{x: '2021-02-28', y: 8}];

let montlyTotals = [{x: '2021-01-01', y: 98},{x: '2021-02-01', y: 120}];

let yourData = {
  datasets: [{
    type: 'line',
    label: 'Daily Generation',
    data: dailyGeneration,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,255,1)',
    xAxisID: 'daily-x-axis',
    yAxisID: 'daily-y-axis',
  },
  {
    type: 'bar',
    label: 'Monthly Totals',
    data: montlyTotals,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)',
    xAxisID: 'monthly-x-axis',
    yAxisID: 'monthly-y-axis',
  }]
};

let yourOptions = {
  scales: {
    // x-Axis by their IDs
    'daily-x-axis': { // <-- v3.x now object "{", not array "[{" anymore
      type: 'timeseries', // <-- try "time" and "timeseries" to see difference
      time: {
        unit: 'day', // <-- set to 'day'
        displayFormats: {
          day: 'MMM DD, YYYY',
          month: 'MMM'
        },
        tooltipFormat: 'dddd, MMM DD, YYYY'
      },
      ticks: {
        minRotation: 80, // avoiding overlapping of x-Axis ticks
        maxRotation: 90,
        color: "blue"
      },
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    'monthly-x-axis': {
      type: 'timeseries', // <-- try "time" and "timeseries" to see difference
      time: {
        unit: 'month', // <-- set to 'month'
        displayFormats: {
          day: 'MMM DD, YYYY',
          month: 'MMM'
        },
        tooltipFormat: 'MMM, YYYY'
      },
      ticks: {
        color: "green"
      },
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    // y-Axis by their IDs
    'daily-y-axis': {
      position: 'left',
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'kWh / day',
        color: "blue"
      },
      ticks: {
        color: "blue"
      }
    },
    'monthly-y-axis': {
      position: 'right',
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'total kWh / month',
        color: "green"
      },
      ticks: {
        color: "green"
      }
    }
  }
};

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  data: yourData,
  options: yourOptions
});
```

```html
<!-- get the latest version of Chart.js, now at v3.5.1 -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<!-- for x-Axis type 'time' or 'timeseries' to work, you need additional libraries -->
<!-- (like moment.js and its adapter) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment"></script>

<canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Why add fill true to the bars? The bar charts don't support the fill property so it doesn't do anything

Comment: @LeeLenalee good point - just edited accordingly

Answer (score -1):

Yes, just use object notation:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [{
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:04'),
          y: 10
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:08'),
          y: 15
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:12'),
          y: 5
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:30'),
          y: 8
        }],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [{
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:04'),
          y: 4
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:08'),
          y: 6
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:12'),
          y: 12
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:30'),
          y: 18
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:022'),
          y: 10
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:38'),
          y: 15
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:52'),
          y: 5
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:59'),
          y: 8
        }],
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code snippet does not quite represent the initial question. You should have read more carefully the question and opened the attached screen-shot.

Comment: I did, multiple line datapoints while less bar datapoints, ain't gonna recreate his example 1 for 1

Comment: Run code snippet of other answer presented and you'll understand .... monthly totals overlaid and spanning over their corresponding daily records (same position: Jan datapoints span over Jan totals, etc ...) - that is the whole point of this question.

Comment: Point of the question is that he had difficulty with charts of different length of amount of data points, that's what he says because also as he says both charts can be produced easily alone so only part he struggled with was getting different amount of data points for each dataset